# Cyclotomic polynomials have integer coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

Why is it clear, what I've highlighted with red in the attached picture?[image]

Comment: Use long division and that $g_n$ is monic.

Comment: Oh!Is your question, why is it clear the content of the red box? Or why the result follows from the content of the red box?

Comment: The question is, why the equation is true.

Comment: The particular part in red is just splitting a product in two. All divisors of $n$ are divided into two groups. One group consists of $n$ itself, the other group consists of all the rest, i.e. of all divisors less than $n$.

Comment: So you have $\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x) = \Phi_n(x) \cdot \prod_{d|n, d<n} \Phi_d(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to consider a form like $a(1)=e(1/2n)+e(-1/2n)$.

From this, one can easily show that $a(n+1)=a(1).a(n)-a(n-1)$.  Now if this is set as a series of equations where $a(1)=x$ and $a(0)=2$, then all of the equations of the type $e(x/2n)+e(-x/2n)$ are automatically expressed in integer multiples of powers of $x$.

The second thing is that by Fermat's little theorem, there is a unique factor in the division of $x^m-y^m$, for each divisor of $m$.  Each of these polynomials have integers attached to each exponent of $xy$.  Now, let $x=e(1/2n), y=e(-1/2n)$.

The unique factor for $2n$ is equal to zero, is the solution for the cyclotomic equation of order $2n$.